# C# WinForms application to linux

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, monodevelop

I've been developing C# application using WinForms(not wpf) and I made it few days ago.
Then my boss asked me can I make it work in linux. I said no, but as I know there is a MonoDevelop to make it real.
Or there are any other solutions about making it real.
The other problem is that I have only windows XP installed on my work computer. MonoDevelop doesnt install on win XP.
So I can try to remake it in MonoDevelop at home, but I never did it before.
Does it take a lot of time to learn monoDevelop and use it for my application?

Comment: You can just use the mono runtime to run your windows forms on linux. You might need to rewrite some code, but you can use visual studio with mono libraries. Search for tutorials. Most if not all of the code should work

Comment: Just create it using Windows, then copy the EXE to linux and start it, using command : "mono mywindows.exe". It should work. If not, then you need to debug it using MonoDevelop in Linux.

Comment: I used Monodevelop for a while on a Debian, I had noticed some stability problems, but I had managed to create an application. I had given up since the IDE was no longer maintained. Besides, the Github repository has been archived.

Comment: On the other hand, there are differences of lib and version of C# between that of mono and of Windows and under Linux, to create a graphic application you must use GTK#.