# How to run windows service on Linux or Mac OS

Tags: c#, linux, windows, winforms

Is it possible to run a Windows service on Linux or Mac OS? I have developed a Windows service that works efficiently on Windows OS, and now I would like to explore the feasibility of running the same service on other operating systems such as Linux or Mac OS. What steps or modifications would be necessary to achieve this cross-platform compatibility? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously "possible", in the worst case reprogramming from scratch. I'm guessing the winforms tag you've used suggests what you think the biggest porting headache will be. Maybe check out [C# WinForms application to linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143933/c-sharp-winforms-application-to-linux) which seems to be asking that same question. An even easier approach might (emphasize "might") be to run virtualbox https://www.pcsteps.com/184-install-virtualbox-linux-mint-ubuntu/ (or see many similar pages, and many similar vm's) under linux, and then just run your service on a windows virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

Linux or macOS has its own way to manage "services", via `systemd` or `supervisor` or other mechanisms. Thus, you won't be able to ship the Windows app to such platforms, but you can write a .NET Core console app based on the same logic and then put it under `systemd` or the desired tool on such OS.